# Two Hard Drives in Dell XPS 1550 15 inch

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I upgraded the small ssd M.2 drive of my Dell 9550 laptop by replacing with 2TB SSD m.2 HARD DRIVE. I left the other SATA Hard drive in place and reinstalled win 10, without changing the RAID configuration. I can now see only one Hard Drive and shows app 1.8 TB of free space. This after the installation of WIN10 OFFICE 365, lIGHTROOM, Photoshop etc. What is the best way to reconfigure the Bois to show two separate drive. I don't want to reinstall windows and programme software unless I HAVE TO. What are the advantages and disadvantages of leaving it as it is with raid configuration. will the SATA 1 TB DRIVE SLOW DOWN THE 2TB SSD and will I lose memory in the current configuration. What if replace the SATA Drive with a SSD
Thank You

Comment: Not an answer.. what does RAID have to do with anything?  As far as I understand.. you can't use RAID between different kinds of drives.  Especially on two different hard drive controllers (which this is).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you put a raid of 2TB M.2 and 1 TB Sata. But the windows installation was not on your old M.2 ?

If the windows installation is on your SATA drive the better way for me it's to have a clean install and cut off the RAID configuration because your Sata Drive slow the M.2. If you change with a SATA SSD as well. The question is did you need the RAID configuration ? If not create a clean install with windows and your program directly on the M.2 and keep the basic Data on your Sata drive and if you can put a SSD to have more speed for your basic Data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Let me explain what I did. Before the upgrade I had one TB sata drive and half size solid state M.2 type drive capacity 32GB. That was the original configuration at purchase in 2016. Like most Dell laptops the Bias was set to Raid On. This was the factory configuration by Dell and I could only see one dirve in the device manager.

I replaced the half size solid state M.2 type flash drive with 2TB Addlink solid state M.2. Straight forward swap, and I did not alter the BIOS booted computer with memory stick with win 10, which was created using windows Creator Tool. The computer without any problem installed WIN 10, however, I could not see the second hard drive in the disk manager. I could see the 2TB solid state drive. Since I posted my question, I opened the laptop and disconnected and remove the 1 TB SATA. The computer booted up and continue to operate normally, which means it was not looking at that drive. I then reinstalled the 1TB   drive and rebooted the computer. it still worked ok, but did not recognise the 1TB DRIVE.
I then changed the Bois setting for the drives from RAID ON TO AHCI. When I rebooted Win started the installation fron the USB stick, but I came unstuck, when it prompted for me to select drive. Although I could now see both the drives windows would not allow me to select either one of them to install windows. Got a error message. Finally I had no choice but to go back to bios and reselect RAID ON and reinstall WIN 10. That is the current position and it appears that I can not use the second drive unless there are some other BOIS Settings tha tI am not aware off.